# Convert data type and concat column in u-sql

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

How to convert datatype and concat columns in U-SQL?

```
@output =
    SELECT DISTINCT (kco.ToString + "-" + hta_ref.ToString + "-" + his_ref.ToString) AS hs_isstaskID,
                    (kco.ToString + "-" + his_ref.ToString) AS HS_IssueID,
                    (kco.ToString + "-" + hta_ref.ToString) AS hs_task_ID,
                    *
    FROM @input;
```

Comment: Hi steve, could you please apply some [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to your question? Also, did you check [the docs of u-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/csharp-functions-and-operators)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToString` is a method so normally takes brackets, eg

```
@output =
    SELECT DISTINCT (kco.ToString() + "-" + hta_ref.ToString() + "-" + his_ref.ToString()) AS hs_isstaskID,
                    (kco.ToString() + "-" + his_ref.ToString()) AS HS_IssueID,
                    (kco.ToString() + "-" + hta_ref.ToString()) AS hs_task_ID,
                    *
    FROM @input;
```

If the data conversions cause problems then you may need to implement `TryParse` as per [here](https://sqlplayer.net/2017/10/functions-in-the-usql-the-hidden-gem-in-the-summer-2017-update/).